# @DataJpaTest does not throw excepted org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using @DataJpaTest for testing my repository.

```
@Query(
  "SELECT AVG(a.rating) as averageValue a.id as someId FROM SomeTable as a  where someTable.id = :id")
 SomReturnObject getExampleTable(@Param(value = "id") String dcsPoolIdPram);
```

The query should not work without `group by` but even though it should fail it does not.
I am using H2 in-memory database. The query fails when I run the app with the Postgres database.

I am using the following configuration.

```
jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema:
        show_sql: true
        jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  security:
    enabled: false
```

This gives an error when we run the application not when testing. Is this a bug of springData ?  or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(
  "SELECT AVG(a.rating) as averageValue a.id as someId FROM SomeTable as a  where someTable.id = :id")
 SomReturnObject getExampleTable(@Param(value = "id") String dcsPoolIdPram);
```

This is not a native query. GroupBy is nessesary only when you use a native SQL query like in the following configuration.

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(a.rating) as averageValue a.id as someId FROM SomeTable as a  where someTable.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
```

Otherwise without using native, `AVG` is just a JPA function which should be provided by the ORM vendor and should be supported for your database.

Take a look here on [HQL/JPQL aggregate functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions) provided by hibernate which is the default ORM vendor in spring data jpa.

As you can see in HQL/JPQL, the aggregate function can be used with `groupBy` or without, and is not the same as SQL language. In case that is used without a groupBy it just applies the aggregate function on the returned results from the HQL/JPQL query.

Comment: this was supposed to be the case but not.  This does not work that was the question.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman `The query should not work without group by but even though it should fail it does not. `

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman based on your question the answer is sufficient to understand why happens what happens. If you wish more help then please provide more info. `For some reason, this gives an error when we run the application ` This is not helpful to provide more useful help

Comment: the question here is why it fails when the application runs but not in the test. your answer is off the topic. I know it should work but it does not.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman `For some reason, this gives an error when we run the application` do you think that this is helpful in question to provide a more insightful answer? I have answered the part on why it works for your test though where it was enough info to be answered.

Comment: you might have miss understood the code the question is why it works on the test but not on production code. your answer does not cover any of that. The same query works if we run the data JPA test but does not when we run the whole application.